# Installed detectem, but "det: command not found"

Tags: python, pip

I am fresh to Python and web scraping.

Following a tutorial introducing `detectem` which could detect the frameworks or languages a website uses, I firstly started to install `docker` to get `detectem` installed.

I encountered a problem `"operation is not permitted"` while installing detectem by `pip`in terminal app, then I googled and used the command `$ pip install detectem --user` by adding a additional `--user` flag.

After than, no annoying red error message poped out, everything looked fine as shown:
[Terminal message screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvBxP.png)
However, after installation, when I tried to use `det` command, the terminal said `command not found` as the following image shows. 
[Terminal error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R61Lc.png)

I tried to google and find out the reason, however, I did not get any useful information about this problem.

Thanks guys if you could give me suggestion on this.

Comment: did you pull the image to docker with `docker pull scrapinghub/splash` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to the directory where detectem was installed: `usr/lib/.../det.extension` and then using the dat command. I believe you can use `pip show <package>` to see the installation path.

Answer (score 0):

With `--user` flag `pip` installs libraries into `~/.local/lib` and scripts into `~/.local/bin`. You need to add the latter to your `PATH`.